# Can't restrict duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to try to restric duplicate entries on MySQL but it keeps showing me this:
**Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Colaboradores\tabela_superadmin\create.php on line 105**

**Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestao\Colaboradores\tabela_superadmin\create.php on line 106**

**line105:**`$get_user=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username',email='$email', mobile='$mobile', user_windows='$user_windows' and id_colaborador='$id_colaborador'");`

line106:`if(mysqli_num_rows($get_user)>0){`

I've already tried more codes but I just can't restrict and show an error message when the entrie is duplicated :/

```
if ($valid) {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //$password = md5($password);
        $get_user=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username',email='$email', mobile='$mobile', user_windows='$user_windows' and id_colaborador='$id_colaborador'");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get_user)>0)
        {
        echo "Details Are Already Submitted";
        }
        else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,mobile,password,role,departamento,empresa,user_windows,centro_custos,id_colaborador,anexo) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($username,$email,$mobile,$password,$user_type,$departamento,$empresa,$user_windows,$centro_custos,$id_colaborador,$anexo));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first `select` query has syntax errors, doesn't it?

Comment: The function `mysqli_query` requires two arguments as stated in the error, you only give one, thats your first problem.

Comment: Also, you can't mix pdo/mysqli api

Comment: @Federkun not really

Comment: no, really. you can't have `where a=b, c=d` inside a select query.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($con,"YOUR_QUERY");
```

You should give mysql connection to the query like above, please refer this link [Mysqli_query](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Because of this error you won't get the existing record entry which is why you didn't get the already exist result.